# ANTLR how to detect rubbish data at end of input

Tags: input, parsing, antlr

When using grammars written in ANTLR, the parser correctly recognizes data from an input stream, but if I have some rubbish text at the end of the input (which is not supposed to be parsed by the grammar) the parser does not complain.

I guess this behavior is all right (I mean the parser did its job and parsed whatever I said it should parse), but is there any trick to detect when there is any data left in the input after the parser has done its job?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the AST produced by ANTLR include the rubbish or does it look OK?  You should be able to get the offset and length of the last token and figure out where it stopped, but its been a while since I've used ANTLR

Comment: The AST is just fine. Everything works fine, the output is generated correctly, just that it would be more user friendly to report an error if they leave anything at the end of the file.

Probably the trick of storing the position of the last token and then searching beyond that will work, but maybe there is some more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12541/scott-stanchfield) already answered on the ANTLR mailing list:

> > Hello,
> >
> > When using grammars written in ANTLR, the parser correctly recognizes
> >     data from an input stream, but if I have some rubbish text at the end of
> >     the input (which rubbish text is not supposed to be parsed by the grammar)
> >     the parser does not complain.
> >
> > I guess this behavior is all right (I mean the parser did its job and parsed
> >     whatever I said it should parse), but is there any trick to detect when there
> >     is any data left in the input after the parser has done its job?
> >
> > Thanks,
> >     Gabi.
>
> Add an EOF token to the end of your start rule
>
> -- Scott

Comment: Yes. Thanks for linking back here.