# ANTLR match to end of input

Tags: regex, parsing, input, antlr

I'm trying to match my grammar to an entire string, and have it error out if it cannot consume the entire input. Basically, this pseudo regex:

```
\whitespace*  [a-zA-Z]+  [-]?  [a-zA-Z]+ \whitespace* $
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147964/antlr-how-to-detect-rubbish-data-at-end-of-input), EOF should work. So, consider this grammar:

```
start : CHARS EOF
      ;

CHARS : ('a'..'z')+
      ;
```

If I set input to `"hello"` in this code:

```
        var ss = new Antlr.Runtime.ANTLRStringStream(input);
        var lex = new autocompleteLexer(ss);
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        var parser = new autocompleteParser(tokens);
        return (BaseTree)(parser.start().Tree);
```

I get an AST with two children, `HELLO` and `EOF`, as expected. But if I set the input to say `"hello#"`, it gives back the same tree, and doesn't complain about the hash at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it was that exceptions were getting trapped by the Lexer instead of propagating into my code. So, by adding this:

```
class ThrowAllLexer: queryLexer
{
    public ThrowAllLexer(ICharStream input): base(input) { }
    public override void  ReportError(RecognitionException e) {
        throw e;
}
```

I now get the proper exceptions, instead of having them be swallowed.